# A Better way to pass Headers to CSV in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I am trying to read data through a GRID in Javascript and the convert it into a CSV file. The CSV is pulling repetitive Headers and the data all over the place. I am very new to Javascript. It would be great if someone can help me.

```
DATA -----------
defaultSortAsc: true
field: "ECCKT_STRIPPED_NAME__r.Name"
focusable: true
formatter: ƒ eccktStrippedNameFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, 
dataContext)
headerCssClass: null
helpText: ""
id: "ECCKT_STRIPPED_NAME"
minWidth: 30
name: "ECCKT_STRIPPED_NAME"
rerenderOnResize: false
resizable: true
selectable: true
sortable: true
width: 300

var exportGrid = function() {
        var headerRow = '';
        var headers = [];
        var str = '';



       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var line = '';
            for (var index in data[i]) {
                if(typeof data[i][index] != "object") {
                    if(!headers[index]) {
                        headers.push(index);
                        if(headerRow != '') headerRow += ',';
                        headerRow += index;
                    }
                    if(line != '') 
                        line += ',';


                    line += '"' + data[i][index] + '"';
                }
            }
            str += line + '\r\n';
        }

        var finalStr = headerRow + '\r\n' + str;
        //To Extract the CSV
        var csv=finalStr;
        var downloadLink=document.createElement("a");
        var blob=new Blob(["\ufeff",csv]);
        var url=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.href=url;
        downloadLink.download="data.csv";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

}

Comment: What is the `data`?

Comment: Hello I have updated the Data

Comment: I can'T see any connection between the data and your code. Please make exactly clear, what your input is, what you expect the output to be and what your actual output is

Comment: Thanks I have explained it more clearly in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668978/would-want-to-extract-data-from-columns-of-a-grid-java-script